# Is an electromagnetic wave weaker at its trough? Or at its 'node'?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is an EM-wave constantly fluctuating in strength or power?  Is it different in some way when it is at its 'peak' amplitude (crest)?

Answer (score 3):

An EM wave is fluctuating in its electric and magnetic field strength. The absolute value of the electric field for example oscillates as a sine wave in space and time: $$E(x, t) = E_0 \sin (kx - \omega t), $$ where $\omega$ is the frequency and $k = 2\pi / \lambda$ the wave vector.
The energy that is stored in a small volume (in free space) if an EM wave is present is given by $$w = \varepsilon_0 E^2,$$
which means it fluctuates according to: $$w = \varepsilon_0 E_0^2 \sin^2 (kx - \omega t)$$
The power per unit area is given by $$P = \varepsilon_0 E^2 c,$$ or alternatively with the $B$ field: $$P = \frac{1}{\mu_0} E B,$$ which also behaves as $\sin^2$.

[image]

For most applications the instantaneous power is of less importance than the average power. This is given by the Poynting vector, which averages over a period and corresponds to half of the peak power.
$$S = \langle P \rangle = \frac{\varepsilon_0 c}{2} E_0^2,$$ where $E_0$ is the peak value of the electric field.

So, yes, it is constantly fluctuating in power, but at a much greater frequency than is relevant for most applications. The only thing that is important is the average power.

Comment: But is it weakest at the trough or the node?

Comment: At the node. That's when the $\sin$ and therefore also $\sin^2$ are 0. At the trough the electric field is just pointing in the other direction. Forming the square of it gives you a positive number again.